# This ain't it Chief

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, alphabet

This is mostly for the memes. I regret existing.

## Rules

- Your code has to output, by either printing or showing in stdout, the phrase `This ain't it Chief.` in that exact format.
- You can only use the characters from the phrase in either format of

  - UTF-8 (`Aa Cc Ee Ff Hh Ii Nn Tt Ss . '`)
  - or hex bytes (`41 61 20 43 63 20 45 65 20 46 66 20 48 68 20 49 69 20 4e 6e 20 54 74 20 53 73 20 2e 20 27`)
- No inputs are allowed via stdin or any form of user input.
- Use `JSFiddle`, `CodePen`, etc. to prove your code works (or a screenshot if needed?)

## Answer Formatting

```
 #Language - Code length in bytes
    some code
 #Comments, laughs, etc.
```

## Scoring

- This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I suggest using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=10) for future challenge ideas: this site has a long history, and many simple ideas for challenges turn out to be duplicate or unpopular for various reasons.

Comment: Fair enough. I do have an idea though, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @lirtosiast What about now?

Comment: I reopened the question as it is no longer a duplicate. You should clarify what exactly *You can only use characters from the phrase "This ain't it Chief."* means. Only the characters `'. CTaefhinst` may appear in the source? Or only their corresponding byte values? Or maybe switching case is allowed?

Comment: okay, thank you! I'll clarify a bit more!

Comment: I still see 3 problems with this challenge: 1. In most languages this is impossible as printing anything requires print("") or similar boilerplate. 2. Allowing a letter but not its byte value is a bit nonsensical, since all code is some sequence of bytes. Many languages don't use ASCII, and we wouldn't want to exclude those. 3. The overall winner will almost surely be in languages like /// that print the source unchanged in this circumstance.

Comment: Do we really need to print `"This ain't it Chief."` rather than `This ain't it Chief.`? May we use the `"` character?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I fixed that, I didn't realize I left the quotes still.

Comment: @lirtosiast I went over those points and changed the question accordingly, as well as clarified the rules of the challenge quite a bit more.

Comment: Are we allowed to use `'` character for the `ain't` or do we need to somehow construct that character? Secondly, it would probably be best to spell out exactly what characters (byte sequences) are allowed, just so there's no ambiguity. Interesting challenge, otherwise.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork there we go, final clarification!

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing the `s` in the list of allowed characters?

Comment: you should also include the uppercase letters in the list of allowed characters

Comment: @altocumulus Added `Ss` to the list.

Comment: @JoKing I edited the question to do so.

Comment: FYI, the answer formatting bit isn't needed. Nor is the bit about JSfiddle. [Try It Online](https://tio.run) generates such things already and supports over 600 languages. Very few languages used here *aren't* on TIO. As for the challenge itself, I don't think any language can work with that instruction set except by sheer coincidence (or intentional design for this challenge).

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 40 bytes

```
'T'h'i's' 'a'i'n'''t' 'i't' 'C'h'i'e'f'.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xz1EPUM9U71YXUE9EUjnqaurlwDZmWDSGSyXqp6mrvf/f0ZqTk4@AA)

Explanation: 'T pushes a T to the stack, etc. CJam has an implicit output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 43 bytes

```
'.ifieiiihi'CiSitiiiSiti''iniiiaiSisiiihi'T
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Jy5pZmllaWlpaGknQ2lTaXRpaWlTaXRpJydpbmlpaWFpU2lzaWlpaGknVA)

> [Draco18s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179332/this-aint-it-chief?rq=1#comment433131_179332): As for the challenge itself, I don't think any language can work with that instruction set except by sheer coincidence

This is one such coincidence; Japt's `i` method prepends its argument to the string it's applied to.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

A function returning the string, just for the lols.

```apl
'This ain''t it Chief'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Xz0kI7NYITEzT129RCGzRME5IzM1Tf1/2qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/pwEA)

> [Draco18s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179332/this-aint-it-chief?rq=1#comment433131_179332): As for the challenge itself, I don't think any language can work with that instruction set except by sheer coincidence

This is one such coincidence; You just need to type `''` to escape a `'` character, instead of using `\'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [A](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A), 1.07e192 bytes

```
insert 1070535411808274876356555204541421987893453317986634005193363842599488570060956068723122679013084672793132737522449327487355527954547514152318677638703786440293483566302887576787267171423983556 A's here
```

Obligatory Lenguage (well this isn't Lenguage but you know what I mean) answer.

[Try the brainfuck online!](https://tio.run/##TY5dCoAwDIMPVJITlF5k@KCCIIIPguev3a/Ly7b0S5ftWc/7ePfLHclEASwGqoTinaXhUChDtGnaAa33lDcYFh08W6bjVO1rDFVh4df0U2YYsxRkS0mpN/MRYDus9Gp2qeX@AQ)

Comment: Your esolangs link for the language doesn’t work

Comment: @caird coinheringaahing Fixed.

Comment: The `C` of the last word isn't capitalized.

Comment: And it was also missing the period at the end. Anyways, fixed.